# Number of Triangle Free Graph with prescribed number of edges

Tags: combinatorics, independence, extremal-graph-theory

Let $f(n, e)$ be the number of triangle-free graphs on $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. From empirical evidence, I am motivated to make the following conjecture.

> **Conjecture**: $f(n,e)$ is unimodal in $e$. In other words, for each $n$ there exists a mode $m = m(n)$ such that $f(n, e) \leq f(n, e + 1)$ if $e < m$, and $f(n, e) \geq f(n, e + 1)$ if $e \geq m$.

I am wondering if this conjecture has been mentioned in literature before since it is natural for such sequences to display some unimodality.

Here's another way to phrase the question.

> **Conjecture**: Let $G$ be the $3$-uniform linear hypergraph whose vertex set is $\binom{[n]}{2}$, and whose edge set is $\{\{i,j\},\{j, k\}, \{k, i\}\}$ for distinct $i,j,k\in [n]$. Then the independence polynomial $Z_G(x)$ is unimodal.

It is known that if we instead consider the $2$-uniform graph with the same vertex set and edge set $\{\{i,j\},\{j, k\}\}$, then $Z_G(x)$ is equal to the matching polynomial $m_G(x)$ of $K_n$, which is unimodal and log-concave.

Edit: [Cross-posted to overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435881/number-of-triangle-free-graph-with-prescribed-number-of-edges).

Comment: Theorem 1.6 [in this paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-2014-00816-X) implies that for all $\delta>0$ there is a $C>0$ such that if $m \ge C n^{3/2}$, then $\binom{n^2/4}{m} \le f(n,m) \le \binom{n^2/4 + \delta n^2}{m}$, which means that $f$ is at least asymptotically unimodal.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, this follows as almost all large triangle-free graphs are bipartite(which is the application of the hypergraph container technique described in the paper). But I'm more interested in seeing that the polynomial is actually unimodal(which involved finer analysis than containers).